# Likes as a many to many

Tags: python, reactjs, django, next.js

I'm making a public prayer journal in full stack(react w/ nextjs and python w/ django) where you can also add and like verses. As the title says the likes are the many to many but I need  it to where any component that displays verse likes will need all of the likes for a user and store them in state. If a verse is in the userLikes for a user, the like button should get checked on render. I need a change handler to submit a userlike to the api whenever the like button is checked, and delete a userlike whenever the like button is unchecked. But I'm unsure of how it's supposed to look exactly, I have trouble translating sentences to code. I already have the api views and data module, as seen below:

user_like

```
class LikeView(ViewSet):
def retrieve(self, request, pk):
    try:
        user_like = UserLike.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = UserLikeSerializer(user_like)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    except UserLike.DoesNotExist as ex:
        return Response({'message': ex.args[0]}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

def list(self, request):
    user_likes = UserLike.objects.all()
    verse = request.query_params.get('verse', None)
    user = request.query_params.get('user', None)
    if verse is not None:
        user_likes = user_likes.filter(verse_id=verse)
    if user is not None:
        user_likes = user_likes.filter(user_id=user)

    serializer = UserLikeSerializer(user_likes, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def update(self, request, pk):
    user_like = UserLike.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user_like.save()

    return Response(None, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

def create(self, request):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.data["uid"])
    verse = Verse.objects.get(pk=request.data["verse_id"])

    user_like = UserLike.objects.create(
        verse=verse,
        user=user
    )
    serializer = UserLikeSerializer(user_like)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def destroy(self, request, pk):
    user_like = UserLike.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user_like.delete()
    return Response(None, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

data module

```
const getLikeByUser = (userId) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 fetch(`${clientCredentials.databaseURL}/userlikes?user=${userId}`)
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then(resolve)
 .catch(reject);
});

const deleteUserLike = (userLikeId) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(`${clientCredentials.databaseURL}/userlikes/${userLikeId}`, {
    method: 'DELETE',
  })
.then(resolve)
.catch(reject);
});

const createUserLike = (userLike) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const userLikeObj = {
    verse_id: Number(userLike.verseId),
    uid: String(userLike.uid),
  };
  fetch(`${clientCredentials.databaseURL}/userlikes`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(userLikeObj),
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => resolve(response.json()))
    .catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```

Here's the like button, just in case

```
<FormControlLabel
          control={(
            <Checkbox
              icon={<FavoriteBorder />}
              checkedIcon={<Favorite />}
              name="checkedH"
            />
            )}
        />
```

I've also tried looking up stuff related to this, but I was unsuccessful